# The Price is Right 'Showcase Showdown'

Tags: python

So I'm trying to run a bunch of simulations of the Price is Right's 'Showcase Showdown'. Essentially, there are three players. The game is played on a huge wheel dubbed "the Big Wheel", which is filled with various cent values in increments of fives from 5¢ all the way up to $1.00; and in this order (5¢, $1.00, 15¢, 80¢, 35¢, 60¢, 20¢, 40¢, 75¢, 55¢, 95¢, 50¢, 85¢, 30¢, 65¢, 10¢, 45¢, 70¢, 25¢, 90¢).

The object of the game is to come as close to $1.00 as you can without going over. Anything over $1.00 loses the game. Each player will take up to two spins of the wheel; After the first spin, the spinner can choose to either stay with what he/she landed on or spin again; on the second spin, whatever the contestant hits will be added to the first score, and (as previously mentioned) if he/she went over $1.00, that contestant is eliminated from the game; otherwise, that player stands under the scoreboard and waits it out.
When all three contestants have taken their spins, the contestant closest to $1.00 wins the game

So I want to run a bunch of simulations of what happens when player 1's first spin is $.50 and he spins again. So it generates a random spin and if it goes over $1.00 they lose, but if it doesn't go over, player 2 spins. Player 2 either beats player 1 or busts, and if they bust, player 3 goes. The code keeps track of how many wins/losses player 1 gets.

Problem is, whatever I put as Player 1's starting value ($.50, $.40, $.30, $.60, etc...) the win percentage is always 15% which isn't right. Any ideas? I know the code is UGLY but forgive I am a noob and trying to learn

```
from random import randint

def test(spin):
    w=0
    l=0
    ties=0
    gain=0
    wins=0
    tests=100000
    for i in range(tests): 
        new=spin+5*randint(1,21) #new money value
        if new>100: #if new value is over 100
            l+=1 # you lose
        else:
            p2_spin_one=5*randint(1,21) #p2's first spin
            if p2_spin_one>=new: #if its higher than p1's final
              l+=1 #p1 loses
            else:
              p2_spin_two=p2_spin_one+5*randint(1,21) #if its lower, 
#spin again
              if p2_spin_two>new and p2_spin_two<=100: #if its higher 
#and less than 100
                l+=1 #p1 loses
              else:
                p3_spin_one=5*randint(1,21) #p3's first spin
                if p3_spin_one>=new: #if its higher than p1's final
                  l+=1 #p1 loses
                else:
                  p3_spin_two=p3_spin_one+5*randint(1,21) #if its 
#lower, spin again
                  if p3_spin_two>new and p3_spin_two<=100: #if second 
#spin is higher and less than 100
                    l+=1
                  elif new==p2_spin_two and new==p3_spin_two:
                    ties+=1
                  elif p2_spin_two>100 and new==p3_spin_two:
                    ties+=1
                  elif p2_spin_two<new and new==p3_spin_two:
                    ties+=1
                  elif new==p2_spin_two and p3_spin_two<new:
                    ties+=1
                  elif new==p2_spin_two and p3_spin_two>100:
                    ties+=1
                  else:
                    w+=1

    return ("\nPlayer 1 spin again when first spin is 
"+str(first_spin)+"\n\n"+"Wins:"+str(w)+"\nLosses:"+str(l)+"\nTies: 
"+str(ties)+"\nWin Percentage: "+str(100*w/tests)+"%")



#Set This equal to the number the person spun first
first_spin=30
print(test(first_spin))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can't fix this because the problem you state doesn't exist.  First, the winning percentage is only *approximately* 15%, and *that* slowly degrades past an initial value of 50.  Had you actually tried all 20 possibilities for the first spin, as well as building in a reasonable strategy for whether the first player should take a second spin, you'd see better results.  I modified your output and looped your main program to produce a table:

```
for first_spin in range(5, 105, 5):
   print(test(first_spin))
```

Output:

```
spin 1:5    W:15736 L:82317 T:1947  Pct: 15.736%
spin 1:10   W:15597 L:82533 T:1870  Pct: 15.597%
spin 1:15   W:15623 L:82359 T:2018  Pct: 15.623%
spin 1:20   W:15700 L:82333 T:1967  Pct: 15.7%
spin 1:25   W:15604 L:82452 T:1944  Pct: 15.604%
spin 1:30   W:15623 L:82458 T:1919  Pct: 15.623%
spin 1:35   W:15598 L:82547 T:1855  Pct: 15.598%
spin 1:40   W:15411 L:82688 T:1901  Pct: 15.411%
spin 1:45   W:15382 L:82756 T:1862  Pct: 15.382%
spin 1:50   W:15004 L:83193 T:1803  Pct: 15.004%
spin 1:55   W:15037 L:83197 T:1766  Pct: 15.037%
spin 1:60   W:14346 L:83994 T:1660  Pct: 14.346%
spin 1:65   W:13800 L:84570 T:1630  Pct: 13.8%
spin 1:70   W:13064 L:85467 T:1469  Pct: 13.064%
spin 1:75   W:11878 L:86769 T:1353  Pct: 11.878%
spin 1:80   W:10587 L:88275 T:1138  Pct: 10.587%
spin 1:85   W:8586  L:90505 T:909   Pct: 8.586%
spin 1:90   W:6467  L:92845 T:688   Pct: 6.467%
spin 1:95   W:3450  L:96216 T:334   Pct: 3.45%
spin 1:100  W:0 L:100000    T:0 Pct: 0.0%
```

The first player has the least information about the game, and thus has the worst winning percentage.  The third player will have the best chance of winning, as she knows *exactly* what total she needs to win the game, and simply takes the second spin if the first isn't good enough.

Comment: Ok I see. You are right I did not try every value, just a handful. How to you get it to print out in such a visually appealing table like that?

Comment: See any on-line tutorial for **print** formatting.  For the most part, I just replaced your new-line characters with tabs.